# Senate actions that require more than majority

Tags: united-states, senate

I know of two actions that the senate can take that requires more than a majority vote, treaties and ending a filibuster.

I then found this:

> (As a point of order), in the Senate, (this section) prohibits consideration of a budget resolution that
> would decrease the Social Security surplus in any fiscal year covered
> by the resolution. Three-fifths vote required to a senate waiver

What is a "point of order"?
And at what other times are super-majorities required in the senate? And are these "laws" or just "procedures"?

Answer (score 1):

The provision you are describing would be a *procedural rule* (but this doesn't mean it couldn't established by a *law*) deeming it to be "not in order" for the Senate to consider any budget resolution that would decrease the social security surplus, unless waived by a three-fifths majority of the Senate.

There are many variants of this that have been proposed over the years. See e.g. https://www.ssa.gov/legislation/legis_bulletin_032201.html

The quote in your question appears to be describing the one from [*Congressional Budget Act 1974*, s. 301(i)](https://www.budget.senate.gov/budgetpointsoforder) (this page also lists many other items deemed not to be in order). Sec. 301(i) establishes that it is "not in order" for the Senate to consider such a resolution.

When something is not in order, it can be blocked when a Senator "raises" a point of order, following which, the Senate would be required to waive it with a three-fifths majority if it wished to proceed.